# Magento 1.9.3.4 Symlinks are enabled warning message

Tags: symlinks, magento-1.9.3.4

I manage my Magento modules with [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) which requires symlinks in Magento to be enabled.

After upgrading to [Magento CE 1.9.3.4](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1934) I see the following message when I log into admin

> Symlinks are enabled. This may expose security risks. We strongly recommend to disable them.

I **accept** the risks associated with symlinks being enabled and would like to remove the admin message as it may cause confusion for other admin users.

What is the best way to remove the *symlinks enabled* warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a explained in [my blog post](https://tomlankhorst.nl/not-valid-template-file-magento-1-9-3-4-symlinks/), the corresponding template is located in:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml`

This means that the best way to remove it is either:

1. create a new `adminhtml` theme and add an empty `symlink.phtml` file.
2. Alternatively, place a layout update in a module that removes the `notification_symlink` block from the admin.

So, in a module of choice, add the following to config.xml:

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Then, create a file with content:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="notifications">
            <remove name="notification_symlink"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Store it in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml`. (or symlink it )

Comment: Good solution, I think changing the translation in Mage_AdminNotification.csv is also a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a local.xml file in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/

and add this code:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="notifications">
            <remove name="notification_symlink"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Or in your custom admin theme...